# Xamrin Forms White Space at Bottom

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mobile, navigation

When I am using Navigation.PushAsync() and setting navigationbar to false when first appearing everything is fine but when going to another page (clicking on the reset password label) and then returning to the first page a blank white space is appearing at the bottom. is this an error or a bug in xamarin forms or is  there something wrong in my xaml? Thanks in advance.[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DeliveryApplication.Tools" 
             xmlns:forms="clr-namespace:Lottie.Forms;assembly=Lottie.Forms"
             x:Class="DeliveryApplication.LoginPage"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">
    
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView x:Name="parent" BackgroundColor="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Constants.PRIMARY_COLOR}}">
            <StackLayout>
                <StackLayout Padding="10, 0, 10, 0" Spacing="10">
                    <forms:AnimationView  x:Name="animationView" Animation="delivery_animation.json" AnimationSource="AssetOrBundle" 
                                      AutoPlay="True" RepeatMode="Restart" RepeatCount="1000000" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                      HeightRequest="200" WidthRequest="200"/>
            
                    <Grid ColumnSpacing="0">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="35" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                
                        <local:RoundedEntry x:Name="usernameEntry" MaxLength="25" Placeholder="Username" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                        <Image x:Name="usernameImage" Source="{local:ImageResource DeliveryApplication.Logos.username.png}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10, 0, 0, 0"/>

                        <local:RoundedEntry x:Name="passwordEntry" MaxLength="25" Placeholder="Password" IsPassword="True" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                        <Image x:Name="passwordImage" Source="{local:ImageResource DeliveryApplication.Logos.password.png}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Margin="10, 0, 0, 0" />
                    </Grid>

                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Start">
                            <CheckBox x:Name="rememberMeCheckbox"/>
                            <Label x:Name="rememberMeLabel" Text="Remember Me" VerticalOptions="Center">
                                <Label.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference rememberMeCheckbox}, Path=IsChecked}" Value="true">
                                        <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Italic, Bold" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Label.Triggers>

                                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="rememberMeLabel_Tapped" />
                                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                            </Label>
                        </StackLayout>

                        <Label x:Name="forgotPasswordLabel" Text="Forgot your password?" TextDecorations="Underline" 
                               HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" >
                            <Label.GestureRecognizers >
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="forgotPasswordLabel_Tapped" />
                            </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Label>

                    </StackLayout>

                    <Button x:Name="signInBtn" Text="Sign In" BorderWidth="5" BorderRadius="10" TextColor="Black"
                            BackgroundColor="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Constants.ACCENT_COLOR}}" Clicked="signInBtn_Clicked"/>
            
                    <ActivityIndicator x:Name="activityIndicator" IsRunning= "True" IsVisible="False"/>
                </StackLayout>

                <StackLayout x:Name="footer" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                    <Label x:Name="tgLbl" FontSize="Small" Text="Powered by Technology-Gate" Margin="0, 0, 0, 10">
                        <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="tgLbl_Tapped"/>
                        </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Label>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

CS:

```
 private async void forgotPasswordLabel_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
            /* forgot password label clicked */
            // Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new ResetPasswordPage());
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new ResetPasswordPage());
 }
```

Comment: Please take a look at [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) and [The reason for removing "thank you"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288179), just explaining the reasons behind my previous edit.

Comment: I reviewed them, thank u.

Comment: Try `<ScrollView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" ...>`.

Comment: Hi @Sam, can you confirm whether this blank space still appear after having replaced your ScrollView by a StackLayout ?

Comment: ok will try both solutions and get back to you

Comment: both solutions did not work.. @Shaw

Comment: Or set backgroundColor of your ScrollView of first stacklayout green, to find out if the blank belongs to the ScrollView.

Comment: @Sam I was not able to reproduce this issue. Please check my screenshot. https://imgur.com/undefined Could you provide more details?

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT what details do u need exactly?

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT the link did not open

Comment: @Sam Check the link:  https://imgur.com/HmaIOch I wanna a code sample to reproduce.

Comment: Try to add bottom padding 0, and fill and expand for stack and scroll view: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/86556/navigation-bar-causes-space-at-the-bottom-of-screen-in-ios

Comment: will try it when I'm able too and get back to u

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT when I'll try what MShah said and get back to u to give u a code sample

Comment: @MShah did not work :(

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT the code has many things dependent on other classes it will take some time to make the code work

Comment: you can do one thing, try create one blank page with background color in all controls and place component one by one what you have in this page. see where the issue occurs and resolve that.

Comment: Without the classes, it works for me. Have you try to put the scrollview inside the stacklayout and make the stacklayout with `VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"`? Does the blank space still exists?

Comment: when I try this solution I'll get back to u. thanks for the help @WendyZang-MSFT

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT did not work either

Comment: @MShah worth a try

Comment: @Sam I was not able to reproduce. We still need more details.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT I will do as MShah said I will try to create a blank page and copy each element individually to see which elements causes this bug

Comment: so I did as @MShah suggested and created a new page and only added a label to go to next page and the problem persisted.

Comment: Navingation.Pushasync(new navigationpage(new yourpagename())); try to open page as a navigation page.

Comment: @MShah I wanted to use PushAsync because I wanted a toolbar with back button in the page I want to go to. So I stopped using PushAsync and created a custom toolbar by using stacklayout and an imagebutton with left arrow icon. So this is for me a workaround and does the job for me. thank u for ur kind help amico.